# Using home screen icon breaks device height on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, safari

I'm using:  `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">`  and adding an icon to my home screen to get around the browser Chrome on iPhone.  However, my code to set div heights to 100% of the device height fails when using this.

```
$(".swiper-container").css({
    "width" : $(window).width(), 
    "height" : $(window).height()
});
```

If I run the page on Safari as normal, it works fine, but not if I run from a saved home screen icon. Any ideas?

Cheers.

MORE INFO:

www.andrewlarking.co.uk/LBSEvents/lbss.html

[image: When Broken]

[image: When in Safari and working]

Comment: any screenshot of how it looks when it breaks?

Comment: Adding the following reduces the oddness, I now have 150 px of white at the bottom:  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta names="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />`

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this using pure javascript without jQuery, put a id=swiper-container into your div and use this code:

```
e = document.getElementById('swiper-container');
e.style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
e.style.width  = window.innerWidth + "px";
```

Comment: Thanks, but the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I use the same JQuery on my body also:

```
$("body").css({ 
    "min-height" : $(window).height()
});
```

This fixes it, although on the iPhone 5 you have the black border like it's an iPhone 4 app.